# nvprof is crashing as it writes a very large file to /tmp/ and runs out of disk space

Tags: cuda, nvprof

**How do I work-around an `nvprof` crash that occurs when running on a disk with a relatively small amount of space available?**

Specifically, when profiling my cuda kernel, I use the following two commands:

```
# Generate the timeline
nvprof -f -o ~/myproj/profiling/timeline-`date -I`.out ~/myproj/build/myexe
# Generate profiling data
nvprof -f --kernels ::mykernel:1 --analysis-metrics -o ~/myproj/profiling/analysis-metrics-`date -I`.out ~/myproj/build/myexe
```

The first `nvprof` command works fine.  The second `nvprof` needs to write a 12GB temporary file to `/tmp` before it can proceed.  Since my 38GB cloud disk only has 6 GB available, `nvprof` crashes.  Assuming I can't free up more disk space, how do I work around this problem?

**Side note:**
It's mostly irrelevant to diagnosing the problem, but nvprof is reporting an `Error: Application received signal 7`, which is a "Bus error (bad memory access)" (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html for more info).

Comment: Get more disk space? In the cloud it should only be a few clicks away. Alternatively, you could also profile a smaller (part of your) program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can direct `nvprof` to use a different temporary directory by setting the `TMPDIR` environment variable.  This is helpful, because since Linux kernel 2.6, there's a decent chance that you have a RAM disk available at `/dev/shm` (see https://superuser.com/a/45509/363816 for more info).  Thus, adding the following at the beginning of one's [`bash`] script will likely work-around your issue.

```
export TMPDIR=/dev/shm
```